# How to make sure that AsyncTask will only execute once?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created an AsyncTask which performs api call.
I am creating multiple AsyncTask using for loop, in OnResume method of Activity.

> `for(int i=0; i<createPostPojoArrayList.size(); i++)
>           {
>               CreatePostPojo createPostPojo = createPostPojoArrayList.get(i);
>               DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask( i, post_recyclerview,createPostPojo, GlobalVariables.mActivity );
>               downloadTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,input);
>           }`

Sometimes api AsycnTask is already running and and as i start asyncTask on OnResume method it excecutes twice

- Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: declare a boolean outside of AsyncTask and change it's value when AsyncTask is running

Comment: @MilaDroid That doesn't work because in the case of an Activity being recreated the boolean would be in the wrong copy of the Activity.

Comment: @GabeSechan you can use OnSavedInstanceState and OnRestoreInstanceState to save it's value.

Comment: @MilaDroid You could.  But that wouldn't help the case where you launch a second Activity that may also start the same AsyncTask to get data from the server.  You could make your solution work with a lot of hoops, but other people have already thought of this and solved all the corner cases.  This is literally why Loaders were created.  Although these days that's no longer the preferred way either.

Comment: I know your solution is better in general case, but mine can solve his problem quicker :)

Comment: How can i Kill all the background processes and start new one ?

Answer (score 0):

The old school way to do this would be a Loader.  The more modern solution is a combination of LiveData and ViewModels.   https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/lifecycle-aware-data-loading-with-android-architecture-components-f95484159de4  has a decent implementation for the latter.